# Back button text too long on navigation bar

Tags: ios

I'm working on my first iOS application. I'm using the navigation controller and I'm running into a small issue. The issue is that the back button's text is too long. Because the text is too long the title is not always centered. I thought about removing the back button but then I loose the swipe to go back feature. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Overide the 'default' back button and replace it with one that just says "back" ?

Comment: use custom back bar  button and self.title =@"yourtitle"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in every `ViewController` where you want back button .

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```